# Is it possible to deploy resources directly using Python and Terraform CDK from code and not CLI?

Tags: terraform, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-cdk

I am looking for a App.deploy() function that can directly deploy/provision infra, just like we have App.synth(). Is it possible to directly deploy resources from code itself without having to deal with CLI for deployment?

Comment: You can execute CLI commands with code, yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no. Even though, as @gshpychka mentioned, you can use code to execute shell commands, that still involves "dealing with the CLI".

The larger question is -- why do you want to avoid using the CLI? Generally speaking, deploying infra is either going to be a one-off task you perform locally, in which case it makes sense to use the CLI, or it is going to be a frequently repeated task performed by a pipeline...in which case it also makes sense for it to be triggered via CLI. What problem are you trying to solve by not interacting with shell commands?

Comment: This is an older question, but the reason I was looking into this was because I want to create a self-service API for infrastructure for developers, I want to reuse existing Terraform modules, and I was hoping not to need anything "out of band" (HTTP API that adds a row to database, then cronjob pipeline that pulls that as an external data source).